# Phonegap/Cordova - Move audio file to the created directory

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I am using Phonegap in which I am using Cordova File plugin. I am able to create directory inside my iPhone. Now I want to move the recorded audio to that directory.

Below is the code for creating directory. Please suggest how I can move the file to this directory.

```
   function FeedVoicesave(callback, appendData) {
    alert("save");
    OnCallback = callback;
    OnAppendData = appendData;
    window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, FeedVoicefail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory("Newfolder", {create: true},gotDir)
}


function gotDir(dir) {
    alert("Created dir "+dir.name);
    alert("Created dir " + dir.fullPath);
    alert("Created dir NativePath" + dir.nativeURL);
}
```